How to implement zooming a canvas centered on the mouse
Thanks to the Zoom/scale at mouse position question, I implement my zoom/scale canvas. However when handling zooming in and out, this code was used:
offset.x = e.offsetX - (e.offsetX - offset.x) * step; 
offset.y = e.offsetY - (e.offsetY - offset.y) * step;

I guess this code is to prevent the content under the mouse from moving away from the mouse area during zooming, but I don't understand why it is implemented this way.
In other words, if I had to write it myself, I think I would get stuck here. I want to understand and master it, but it seems very difficult.


const canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const step = 1.02;
const maxScale = 8;
const minScale = 0.3;

let isdragging = false,
  scale = 1,
  offset = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  };

const drawCanvas = () => {
  ctx.setTransform([1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  ctx.setTransform(scale, 0, 0, scale, offset.x, offset.y);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 10, 20, 30);
  ctx.fillRect(100, 100, 20, 30);
};

requestAnimationFrame(drawCanvas);

canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
  isdragging = true;
});

canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
  isdragging = false;
});

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
  if (isdragging) {
    offset.x += e.movementX;
    offset.y += e.movementY;
    requestAnimationFrame(drawCanvas);
  }
});

canvas.addEventListener("wheel", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (e.deltaY <= 0) {
    if ((scale * step) >= maxScale) {
      return
    }
    scale *= step;
    offset.x = e.offsetX - (e.offsetX - offset.x) * step; // why?
    offset.y = e.offsetY - (e.offsetY - offset.y) * step; // why?
  } else {
    if ((scale / step) <= minScale) {
      return
    }

    scale /= step;
    offset.x = e.offsetX - (e.offsetX - offset.x) / step; // why?
    offset.y = e.offsetY - (e.offsetY - offset.y) / step; // why?
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(drawCanvas);

}, {
  passive: false
});

const btn = document.querySelector("button");
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  scale *= step
  drawCanvas();
});
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#canvas {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
<button>scale * step</button>




They are added there to zoom in/out according to the mouse pointer location. You can test it like, trying to zoom in/out when your mouse pointer is on one of the rectangles. Then, remove these code blocks that you commented as why, and try the same process again. After removing these code blocks, it will zoom in/out towards the center of the screen cause the offset values are 0 so it takes the center of the screen as reference. With these code blocks, it zooms in/out by taking the rectangle as the center cause the offset values are calculated similarly to the rectangle's position
